# C++20 Modules std.ixx STL Static/Global Scope References

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

Following instructions by Microsoft, I couldn't get the std module to build and not have a versioning error, so I went ahead and just added the file:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32213\modules\std.ixx

to my project and I import it into my module interface files. My only issue is I can't access ::localtime_s because it is one of the static-inline/global functions not in the std namespace. Including <time.h> in the global module space creates issues with macro redefinitions. Is there something I am missing?

```
export module MyModule;

import std;

export namespace nspace1 {

    void TimeFunction();

}

namespace nspace1 {

    void TimeFunction()
    {
        std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);

        std::tm* now{};

        void* result = ::localtime_s(now, &t); <== dne

    }

}
```

The intellisense error is it is not found in the global space which makes sense for localtime_s because it is static, but _localtime64_s is just global and it says the same thing. Dropping the double colons just changes the error message to cannot be found.

Comment: The non-static _localtime64_s is not found either.

Comment: @RebekaFox The example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-s-localtime32-s-localtime64-s?view=msvc-170 works fine under VS2022.

Comment: Is this in response to modules? Because the link is not module related.

Comment: From my experiment with C++ modules on MSVC, I learnt that if you `import std;`, then you cannot `#include` any standard header (except a couple of macro-only headers `<cerrno>`, `<cstdarg>` and `<cassert>`). This implies you cannot use any non-standard Microsoft extension function in CRT. My recommendation: stay with standard C++ library. You gain portability also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code builds ok on my machine.

(Version 17.5.0 Preview 3.0)

`import std;` is a C++23 feature. I hope vendor support is getting better.

```
module;

#include <time.h>

export module MyModule;

import std;

export namespace nspace1 {

    void TimeFunction();

}

namespace nspace1 {

    void TimeFunction()
    {
        std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);

        std::tm* now{};

        auto result = ::localtime_s(now, &t);
        //auto result = localtime_s(now, &t); // ok, too

    }
}
```

EDIT: As of MSVC 17.6.0 Preview 3.0, it is not necessary to add std.ixx file. The IDE knows how to build. If added it causes compile error.

Comment: I'm assuming that you built std separately here, like you are supposed to. I do explicitly state I had issues with this. Now that I know this I will extend my efforts, but it would be nice to know why it works the one way and not the other. Thank you for your post.

Comment: I added std.ixx through Solution Explorer. I built the project inside the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for updating me on this. I thought I was thorough on isolating this case and there being warnings of macro redeclarations. I thought it was weird that I was getting warnings, because I didn't see the referenced macros in the file. After your comments I have tried again and it works on both /W3 and /W4 so thanks.